# Adding a message icon to Dijit Dialog

Tags: dialog, dojo, imageicon

I am new to Dojo and I am trying to create a (dijit) Dialog pop up that displays a message and an icon. I am doing this programatically and I have managed to create the Dialog but I have not been able to figure out how to add the icon image into the dialog.

I found a solution that seemed promising but it ended up not working.

Heres what I tried

dialog declaration in Dialog.js

```javascript
this.myDialog = new Dialog({

                        title: this.title,
                        content: "<center>"+this.content+"</center>"+"<br>",
                        doLayout: false,
                        style: "width: 50%"
                        });
```

Icon class in CSS

```css
.myIcon {
 background: url("fakepath/images/32.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 text-align: left;
}
```

Declaring the dialog in the jsp

```xml
<ui:dialog title="Dialog Box" id="myDialog" content="Hi There"
     buttonType="OK" iconClass="myIcon"></ui:dialog>
```

I get a dialog pop up with a message but no icons or even a hint of one (the empty placeholder you get when the image path is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dijit/Dialog` does not support an `iconClass` property, so nothing is being done with the value you set.

Where are you expecting the icon to appear?  In the title bar or as part of the content window?

If you want it in the title bar then you will need to override the template that the Dialog uses when you instantiate the widget and make a place for the icon in the overridden template.

See `dijit/templates/Dialog.html`

If you want it as part of the content window, then you need to write that into the html that you set as content.

```
<div class="dialogMessage">
   <div class="dijitInline messageIcon error></div>
   <div class="dijitInline message">
      <span>Your message here.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it as part of my content (alert/information/message icon). Is there anyway I can add it programatically ? because i need to deliver a reusable widget which has a .tag/.js/.css file  . So I cant add it from the JSP/HTML

Comment: Yes, you can do it programmatically.  You could write a custom Dialog widget that automatically sets the content based on the properties you set on the widget (ie iconClass).  I have done something similar (no jsp) here -> https://github.com/cswing/evinceframework/tree/master/evf-web-js/src/dojo/evf/dialog  Maybe you can use this as a base for what you are trying to do. See util.js